# ssh remote commands without known_hosts entry

Tags: linux, ssh, printing, remote-access

I have written a python application which takes inputs from a user about a printer. details like printer name, ip address, port to use and then it issues a ssh command to build that print queue (CUPS queue).

the server on which the printers are built are referenced by various names like

1. linuxserver1
2. linuxserver1.domain.com

basically just the hostname and the fully qualified domain name.

I am using the root account for all these tasks.

on the linux server 
/root/.ssh/known_hosts have an entry for 'linuxserver1' but not for the FQDN 'linuxserver1.domain.com'

when the python application sends the ssh. there is a prompt from the ssh connection about the RSA key like this one

```
$ ssh root@linuxserver1.domain.com
 The authenticity of host '192.168.20.10 (192.168.20.10)' can't be established.
 RSA key fingerprint is 4e:cb:44:bd:c5:1a:c1:1f:b3:43:2e:56:56:f8:e0:af.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

there are about 500 servers, so I cannot log into each one and disable this check by modifying the ssh-config or adding an entry in known_hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array of servers

```
declare SERVERS=('ip_1' 'ip_2'................... 'ip_n);
for i in "${SERVERS[@]}"
do
ssh: ssh-copy-id -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$i
done
```

Comment: thanks Sudhir, that did not answer my question directly, but it gave me some ideas which I have used in the past to use things like expect. will try those. thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you share the error which are u getting from there?

Comment: there was no error. just that I was getting a prompt like this when a ssh connection was made. $ ssh root@linuxserver1.domain.com
 The authenticity of host '192.168.20.10 (192.168.20.10)' can't be established.
 RSA key fingerprint is 4e:cb:44:bd:c5:1a:c1:1f:b3:43:2e:56:56:f8:e0:af.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: you can add -y option in script